# Is there any way to remove the left-column in Stripe Customer Portal?

Tags: iframe, stripe-payments

I'd like to integrate the Customer Portal in an iframe, so my customers could manage their invoicing from my website.

Is there any way to remove the left column of the customer portal (with the brand logo, and a text)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can customize it to remove a portion of the portal like you suggest. A portal session is the entry point to the portal and none of the customizable settings, https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management/configure-portal#customize-the-portal controls that. However, you can control the look of the portal to match your branding here, https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management/configure-portal#branding.